# Typescript error: Type 'Document[]' is not assignable to custom type

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

There is a simple nestJS service, which returns the result of a mongoDb query.
As you can see, I tried to set the expected result type, which is an array of documents.

```
class MyDataset {
    group: string
    location: string
    type: string
    reported: Date
}

async getDatasets(): Promise<Array<MyDataset>> {
    const Collection = this.db.collection('collection')
    const result = await Collection.find({}).toArray()
    return result // <-- ts error
}
```

But I do get the TS error

```
Type 'Document[]' is not assignable to type 'MyDataset[]'.
Type 'Document' is missing the following properties from type 'MyDataset': group, location, type, reported
```

I don't see, what I am doing wrong. Could somebody explain the problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error implies a mismatch between the type you're expecting `MyDataset` and the one `Collection.find({}).toArray()` is returning. The mongo db documentation states the [toArray()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/#mongodb-method-cursor.toArray) methods returns an array of Documents.

This replicates the same behaviour:

```
type DocumentA = {
    group: string
    location: string
    type: string
    reported: Date
}

type DocumentB = {
    anotherField: string
}

const arrayOfDocumentsA = () => {
    const res: DocumentA[] = [];
    return res;
}

const arrayOfDocumentsB = () => {
    const res: DocumentB[] = [];
    return res;
}

const getDatasets = (): Array<DocumentA> => {
    return arrayOfDocumentsB(); // ts error
};
```

This will error out with the following error:

```
Type 'DocumentB[]' is not assignable to type 'DocumentA[]'.
  Type 'DocumentB' is missing the following properties from type 'DocumentA': group, location, type, reported ts(2322)
```